# Data saving structure best practices in ElastcSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana

I want some logging for my service data.

my log has like this(jus example):
user-sigin , user-signup, user-actions..

So,

I structured it as follows.

index:

```
servicename-user-singin-2017-11-21-signin,

servicename-user-singin-2017-11-21-signup,

servicename-user-singin-2017-11-21-useractions
...
```

And Thats indexing datas has diffrent types

I wondered what better practice was(data categorization).

Anyone Helps?

thanks.